# How do I pull data from both of these files?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to create a map that tracks COVID-19 confirmed cases by county using FIPS codes. How am I able to make this code gather the data from both of those data files?

If you run the code as is (NY times data) then the map does not fill in counties with zero cases as zero cases. This is because the NY times data does not list the data for the places with zero cases. The other data does list places with zero cases. So, whatever doesn't get filled in with the NY times data I would like to fill in with the other data set. How do I do this? Or how do I fix my problem? Also, when hovering over the map how do I make it state the county name instead of the FIPS number?

Furthermore, how do I make this a live map that auto-updates when there is new data?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-counties.csv",
                   dtype={"fips": str})

df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/03-28-2020.csv",
                   dtype={"fips": str})


import plotly.express as px

                          )

fig = px.choropleth(df, geojson=counties, locations='fips', color='cases',
                           color_continuous_scale="dense",
                           range_color=(0, 100),
                           scope="usa", 
                           labels={'cases':'Confirmed COVID:19 Cases'},

                          )
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Comment: Currently your second `pd.read_csv` call is overwriting the variable `df` you have created with the first call. Try creating separate variables and then filling null values using `df1.fillna(df2)`. For the display question, have you looked at the documentation provided by plotly?

Comment: I am using [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/jacobkrucinski/coronavirus-covid-19-data-extrapolation) for COVID data visualization and I created such a plot already (towards the bottom of the page). Once you see it, click on the code button to see my code.